# Javascript: toggling an input label on and off only works on the last label in the form

Tags: javascript, forms, toggle

I'm trying to make labels toggle on and off when their respective inputs are clicked. 
However my code just turns off the last label in the form. I know jQuery would be the best solution, but I'm trying to get to grips with Javascript. I would greatly appreciate any help.
Many thanks! :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=foo;

function foo(){ 

    function ToggleLabels(form){
        var oForm = document.forms[form];

        // this function will add events to objects.
        function addEvent(object,eType,eWindowsType,func,bubble){
            if(window.addEventListener){
                object.addEventListener(eType,func,bubble);
            }
            if(window.attachEvent){
                object.attachEvent(eWindowsType,func);
            }
        }

        //toggles the display of the labels
        function toggle(input,label){
        alert(label.innerHTML)
            if(input.value == ''){
                if(label.style.display == 'none'){
                    label.style.display = 'inline';
                }
                else{
                    label.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            else{
                label.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        // Loop through all text inputs in the form and add the toggle functionality
        for(var i=0; i < oForm.length; i++){
            if(oForm.elements[i].type == 'text'){               
                var oInput = oForm.elements[i];
                var oLabel = oInput.previousSibling;
                addEvent(oInput,'click','onclick',function(){toggle(oInput,oLabel)},false);

            }               
        }
    }

    new ToggleLabels(0);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="name" id="nameL">Name: </label><input id="name" type="text" name="name"/>
    <label for="age">Age: </label><input type="text" name="age"/>
    <label for="gender">Gender: </label><input type="text" name="gender"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple change on your code will do the trick:

```
// Loop through all text inputs in the form and add the toggle functionality
    for(var i=0; i < oForm.length; i++){
        if(oForm.elements[i].type == 'text'){               
            var oInput = oForm.elements[i];
            addEvent(oInput,'click','onclick',function(){toggle(this,this.previousSibling)},false);

        }               
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You make the typical mistake of creating functions in a loop. JavaScript has only function scope, not block scope. Thus doing

```
for(...) {
    var value = "something";
}
```

is the same as

```
var value;
for(...) {
    value = "something";
}
```

That means every of the anonymous functions refer to the same `oInput` and `oLabel`. And those will have the value of the last iteration of the loop.

You have to introduce a new scope, e.g. with an *immediate function*:

```
for(var i=0; i < oForm.length; i++){
    if(oForm.elements[i].type == 'text'){             
        addEvent(oInput,'click','onclick',(function(oInput, oLabel) {
            return function(){toggle(oInput,oLabel)},false);
        }(oForm.elements[i], oInput.previousSibling)));
     }               
}
```

but more readable would be to create a dedicated function:

```
function getHandler(oInput, oLabel) {
    return function(){toggle(oInput,oLabel)},false);
}

// later

for(var i=0; i < oForm.length; i++){
    if(oForm.elements[i].type == 'text'){             
        addEvent(oInput,'click','onclick',getHandler(oForm.elements[i], oInput.previousSibling));         
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I knew it was something very basic that I just wasn't getting. Big thumbs up!

Comment: @Gary Ryan: Please consider [@logui's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021843/javascript-toggling-an-input-label-on-and-off-only-works-on-the-last-label-in-th/5022170#5022170). It is easier and does not involve closures.

Comment: Thanks, loguis solution works great :) I'm glad you pointed out the closure issue though. I need to get a better understanding of that.

Comment: @Gary Ryan: I know, this is something which can be tricky. Well, now you know a bit better :)

Answer (score 0):

:) the previous 2 answers about closures explain what you did wrong.

I changed your toggle method to accept an element as it's input (instead of the 2 elements that you were attempting to pass in).

I then changed your toggle method to retrieve all of the Label elements in the parent node of the element passed into the method (using the getElementsByTagName method). I then retrieved the ID of the element that was passed in and compared it to each of the label elements retrieved. If the ID of the element matched the For property of the label, I set the label's style to "display:none"...otherwise I set the label's style to "display:inline".

OH yeah, one last thing I changed...I gave your inputs "ids" :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=foo;

function foo(){ 

    function ToggleLabels(form){
        var oForm = document.forms[form];

        // this function will add events to objects.
        function addEvent(object,eType,eWindowsType,func,bubble){
            if(window.addEventListener){
                object.addEventListener(eType,func,bubble);
            }
            if(window.attachEvent){
                object.attachEvent(eWindowsType,func);
            }
        }

        //toggles the display of the labels
        function toggle(element){
            var labels= element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("label");
            var elementName = String(element.id);

            for(i=0; i<labels.length; i++)
            {  
              var labelFor = String(labels[i].htmlFor);

              if(labelFor  == elementName )
              {  hideLabel(labels[i])
              }else{
                  displayLabel(labels[i]);
              }
            }
        }

        function displayLabel(label){
           if(label != undefined){
            label.style.display = 'inline';
           }
        }
        function hideLabel(label){
           if(label != undefined){
            label.style.display = 'none';
           }
        }

        // Loop through all text inputs in the form and add the toggle functionality
        for(var i=0; i < oForm.length; i++){
            if(oForm.elements[i].type == 'text'){               
                var oInput = oForm.elements[i];
                var oLabel = oInput.previousSibling;
                addEvent(oInput,'click','onclick',function(){toggle(this)},false);

            }               
        }
    }

    new ToggleLabels(0);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="name">Name: </label><input id="name" type="text" name="name"/>
    <label for="age">Age: </label><input type="text" id="age" name="age"/>
    <label for="gender">Gender: </label><input type="text" id="gender" name="gender"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

-Frinny

Comment: Thank you. I like how you've changed the toggle element to accept just the element and then get the label from there. Brilliant work, much neater.